# Simplifiying proram which generates prime number from 2 to n

Tags: c, performance

I have found the solution to the programs, but i got running time error. I need to simplify the sourse code, so it could be compiled in 0.3 second. Please help me simplify the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, c=0, num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    for(i=2; i<=num; i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=sqrt(i);j++)
        {   if(i%j==0)
            c++; 
        }
        if(c==1)
        {   printf(" %d", i);
        }
        c=0;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you heard about the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)?

Comment: `compiled in 0.3 second` - do you actually mean `execute in 0.3 seconds`? It's hard to see how you could make this significantly simpler (shorter) .

Comment: No need to  call `sqrt` in the loop condition, call it once at the start of the loop. Also you don't need to test fr multiples of 2, if the number isn't dividable by 2, it's also not diviable by any multiple of 2, alone this will make your program twice as fast.

Comment: _"Won't it get more redundant? "_ ?? Be more specific, what would get more redundant than what?

Comment: So the sqrt can be called at the start even if the input option is in the loop?

Comment: Sorry the redundant part was my comment to Eugene Sh.

Comment: Also the test `if(c==1)` does not nee to be in the loop.

Comment: @KhaelaFortunela inside the `for(j=1;j<=sqrt(i);j++)` loop, `i` doesn't change

Comment: How big can `num` be?

Comment: if i put the sqrt ouside for, then i would need to break apart function f, isn't it?

Comment: the limit is 100001

Comment: ... sigh... `int max = sqrt(i); for(j = 1; j <= max; j++) ...`

Comment: it doesn't work if i put if(c==1), since i need to print numerous numbers

Comment: Even with your original unoptimized code, for the upper limit of `100001` (as you said), it takes 0.12s to run. Are you sure that's the problem?

Comment: Just [skip the even](https://wandbox.org/permlink/e2s2fH1LJxlLBhnU) numbers, it should be [fast](http://quick-bench.com/iletpLDAbhKOKQ3Co6EzQMHaXug) enough, even if there are faster algorithms.

Comment: @ChatterOne really? why didn't it work on mine?T.T the limit i could go is 0.38 s

Comment: If you build an array of primes found so far, you only need to test *them* as divisors (up to the square root).

Comment: Another thing - break the inner for loop if the tested number is found to be not prime.

Comment: `for(i=2; i<=num; i++)` is an infinite loop  (or UB) when `num == INT_MAX`.